# Old webcam recorded video not playing

Tags: video, playback

I have this video (length 1-2 min) recorded on Dell webcam 3-4 years ago. It played smoothly at that time. Now when I play it, for first 40 seconds it plays well but after that video goes blank and audio stops. Video continues to move forward but without video and audio, just blank .

Is there by any chance I can recover this video? If yes, how?
It's an AVI file, 550 MB.

Codec -

```
Video
ID                             : 0
Format                         : RGB
Codec ID                       : 0x00000000
Codec ID/Info                  : Basic Windows bitmap format. 1, 4 and 8 bpp versions are palettised. 16, 24 and 32bpp contain raw RGB samples
Duration                       : 1mn 34s
Bit rate                       : 47.1 Mbps
Width                          : 640 pixels
Height                         : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio           : 4:3
Frame rate                     : 30.000 fps
Bit depth                      : 8 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)             : 5.114
Stream size                    : 533 MiB (97%)
```

Comment: Try converting it with a tool from that time: http://www.squared5.com/

Answer (score 0):

To me sounds like a lack of original codecs. Why don't you start by posting a ffprobe of the file? The container is AVI but we doesn't know anything about the codec.

```
ffprobe file.avi
```

**FFprobe** is a tool found in the FFmpeg package: https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: I have downloaded above package, but don't know how to use. Will you help?

Comment: @HungryDB 
 
Assuming you are using a windows os you should download a package like this: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/ffmpeg-20151022-git-a7c5005-win32-static.7z Then you should unzip it, inside there should be a file called ff-prompt.bat, run it. There you could type something right? Type "ffprobe your_file_location" (without quotes), it should give you a long result, take a screenshot. Edit your original question and add a screenshot in it.

Comment: i have updated codec information. Kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: Does it play correctly with ffplay i.e. `ffplay filename.avi`?

Comment: I used media player classic to get codec information. Not ffprobe. Should i download ffmpeg package?